# need to generate unlimited number of unique id's with jQuery

Tags: jquery

extreme n00b here... I've got a number of elements (dynamically generated by back end so it could be quite a few) and all need a unique id.  I'm trying to work out how to do this wth jQuery and not doing so well.  Any help is appreciated.

In the code below, I'd want each "bar" div to get a unique id, like id1, id2 etc etc

```
<div class="foo">
    <ul  class="bar">
</ul>
    <ul  class="bar">
</ul>
    <ul  class="bar">
</ul>
    <ul  class="bar">
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

```
var id = 1;
$('.foo .bar').each(
   function() { 
     $(this).attr('id', 'id' + id++); 
});
```

In order to bind event listeners to these, you have to either do it in the loop or use `live`.

Comment: Happens all the time to me as well - I must try be quicker.

Comment: You missed a paranthesis after `this`, should be `$(this).attr('id', 'id' + id++); `

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var ctr = 1;
$.each( $(".bar"), function( ) {
    $(this).id = "id"+(ctr++);
} );
```

Using jQuery

- [**$(".bar")** class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to grab all the elements with class bar,
- [**$.each(selector, func)** utility](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate over the bar elements and address them one by one,
- [**$(this)**](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/) to get a jQuery wrapped element that's current in the iteration,
- and **"id"+(ctr++)** simply carries out the logic of assigning id value to attribute, incrementing # each time

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeAllTheThingsThatTheOPRequested(num){
    var ms = document.createElement('div');
    ms.setattribute("class","your_class_name");
    var uls=[];
    for(var i=0;i<num;i++){
        var tmp = document.createElement('ul');
        tmp.setattribute("class","your_class_name");
        ms.addChild(tmp)
        uls.push(tmp);
    }
    document.body.addChild(ms);
}
```

Comment: Um, the OP wants this in jQuery.

Comment: sorry, didn't see, shame me :(

Comment: @deceze - true, but its not in jQuery style.